# NuGet .NET package reference not found

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio

I've added the AutoMapper as a reference to my project, but it does not pick it up.
I also use AutoMapper in another project in the same solution and that works fine.

I've also noted that the package has not been added in the package.config file.
Why does it not pick it up as a reference in the code?

The below screenshot will explain my scenario:

[image]

Comment: What version of .Net does your project target and is that aligned with the dependencies of the particular version of AutoMapper?

Comment: The project is on .Net 4.5.2 and the AutoMapper is version 7.0.1 (which targets .Net 4.5+)

Comment: What puzzles me is that it works on a project in the same solution (also targets .Net 4.5.2) and it works 100% in that project. The only difference is the 1 is a class library and the other 1 is a Web App (API). Could that maybe be the reason?

Comment: Have you tried the good old - restart visual studio, clean, rebuild solution?

Comment: @Ppp Was 1 of the first things I tried lol. I created a static method in my business layer and calling it from the project where the reference is not working. Not ideal, but what can a man do